# Contact() got an unexpected keyword argument 'listing'

Tags: django, django-views, django-templates

`from django.shortcuts import render, redirect
from .models import Contact
from django.contrib import messages

## Create your views here.

`def Contact(request):`
`if request.method == 'POST':`
`listing_id = request.POST['listing_id']`
`listing = request.POST['listing']`
`name = request.POST['name']`
`email = request.POST['email']`
`phone = request.POST['phone']`
`message = request.POST['message']`
`user_id = request.POST['user_id']`
`realtor_email = request.POST['realtor_email']`

```
    contact.save()
    messages.success(
        request, 'Your request has been submitted, a realtor will get back to you soon')
    rn redirect('listings'+listing_id)
```

`

**i'm trying to save the data from database. but give the error TypeError.**

Comment: change your view function name to something else as you already have a Model with the same name and you are importing it. change the view name to contact_view something else

Comment: Please format your question correctly, it's not clear what you are doing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This statement

```
from .models import Contact
```

You have defined a method with the name `Contact` and you are trying to import a module from the `.models` and also it's name is `Contact`

So to fix the issue.

You need to change the Method name or import the module with any alias name.

for Eg:

```
from .model import Contact as contact_module
```

or change the method name to any like..

```
def contact_method(request):
  #.....
```